# Google Calendar Api. cannot connect to other user calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I understand that there were already similar questions here, but the answers to them did not help me.
    Trying to connect through a service account to the calendars of users who are part of the domain. For connection I use Google API PHP Client (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)
    Account setup followed the instructions (https://developers/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

Here's my code:

```php
    <?php
    require '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();

    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json');
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->authorize();
    $scopes = implode(' ', [Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR, Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS]);
    $client->setScopes($scopes);
    $client->setSubject('user@email.com');

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $optParams = [
        'maxResults' => 10,
        'orderBy' => 'startTime',
        'singleEvents' => TRUE,
        'timeMin' => date('c')
    ];
    $results = $service->events->listEvents('root@email.com', $optParams);
    $events = $results->getItems();
```

And then I get an authorization error:

```
Error: {
  "error": "unauthorized_client",
  "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."
}
```

Can you tell me if someone 's already faced a mistake like this? Should the root@email.com be mail or mail that was generated during access setup? Or is the problem somewhere else at all?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Which scope are you using when you authorize your service account? root@email.com and user@email.com belong to the same domain?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same domain

Comment: Ok, what about the first question? Are you using the same scopes that you authorized in the admin panel?

Comment: For authorization, I use the mail that was generated for the service account project@project-270012.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "project",
    "private_key_id": "***",
    "private_key": "***",
    "client_email": "project@project-270012.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "***",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "***",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "***"
}

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually correct. Be sure you authorized your service account to use the same scopes you are trying to use in your code. This is a common issue with service accounts. 
Here a walk-through from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation):

1. Go to your G Suite domain’s Admin console.
2. Select Security from the list of controls. If you don't see Security listed, select More controls from the gray bar at the bottom of the page, then select Security from the list of controls.
3. Select Advanced settings from the list of options.
4. Select Manage API client access in the Authentication section.
5. In the Client name field, enter the client ID obtained from the service account creation steps above.
6. In the One or More API Scopes field enter the scopes required for your application (for a list of possible scopes, see Authorize requests).
   For example, if you require domain-wide access to Calendar and Calendar Events: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events
7. Click the Authorize button.